# Find Empty Cell from activecell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie here need help to find the next emptycell in a range from the activecell.row....

```
Sub FindNextCell()
'
'Macro1 Macro

Cells.Find(What:="", _
             After:=Range("F2:I22")(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, _
             Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)), _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
             SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
             MatchCase:=False, _
             SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `Find` method, it's better to set the result as a `Range`.

Of course, there is a possibilty the `Find` will not return any results (in case it doesn't find another empty cell in the specifed range), that's why we add `If Not EmptyRng Is Nothing Then`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindNextCell()

Dim FindRng As Range, EmptyRng As Range

' define the Range to search according to ActiveCell current row
Set FindRng = Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row & ":I" & ActiveCell.Row)

' COMMENT : need to cheat a little to get the first cell founds in the searched range
'           by starting from the last column in the range, Column "I"
'           Otherwise, will return the second cell found in the searched range
Set EmptyRng = FindRng.Find(What:="", after:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "I"), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

' found an empty cell in the specified range
If Not EmptyRng Is Nothing Then
    EmptyRng.Select
Else ' unable to find an empty cell in the specified range
    MsgBox "Unable to find an empty cell in " & FindRng.Address & " Range"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to mention my active cell will be on column(1) and i want to find the next emptycell on that active row in the range i mention.

Comment: @TerranceMatthew let me make sure I understand, let's say your `ActiveCell` is Cell A3, you want to find the next empty cell in row 3, from Columns F to I ? If all cells in row 3 are full, should you go to the next row ? or just show a `MsgBox` or something similar ?

Comment: yes I want to find the next empty cell in row 3, from Columns F to I and  If all cells in row 3 are full, just show a MsgBox or something similar

Comment: works perfect you are a life saver but  one little problem it select cell on column g first then loop back to column f

Comment: @TerranceMatthew try edited code, you need to fo a little "over" to get the first cell found in the searched range (see comment inside my code)

Comment: @TerranceMatthew don't forget to mark as answer by putting the little **v**